# Direct message channels, but still getting optimistic lock exception

Tags: spring-integration

Given account with accountId and SomeLUW, AnotherLUW (logical unit of works), where account is updated in boths LUWs

When I try to do the following:

```
SomeLUW luw1 = new SomeLUW(accountId);
messagingTemplate.send(channel1, new GenericMessage<>(luw1));

AnotherLUW luw2 = new AnotherLUW (accountId);
messagingTemplate.send(channel2, new GenericMessage<>(luw2));
```

Sometimes, optimistic locking exception occurs.
I don't understand why it can be, I'd assume it is **sequential processing**

Because I use direct channels:

```
MessageChannels.direct()
    .datatype(AnotherLUW.class)
    .get();
MessageChannels.direct()
    .datatype(RedemptionLUW.class)
    .get();
```

and in logs, I can find only one thread (typical SI **DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1**)

I have errorHandler which makes JMS broker redeliver, but logs are polluted with exceptions

Any idea why this is the case?

Answer (score 0):

Well, since your process is started from the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`, that really maybe a fact for you that some messages are processed in different threads from there. Therefore in parallel.

Right, it is **sequential process**, but when everything is done in the same thread.

Consider to use `DefaultLockRegistry` to seize a mutual access to the resource. I guess in your case it is JPA.

Comment: How can I use DefaultLockRegistry. I am trying to find any example, but I couldn't find any

Comment: You can take a look into https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-core/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/support/locks/DefaultLockRegistryTests.java. But general purpose is: obtain a lock from the registry by some `key`, lock it during process and unlock in the end, like regular one. Only the difference that you are not blocked there for different keys.